# request_irq succeeds but interrupt is never detected

Tags: linux, serial-port, embedded-linux, atmel, irq

I am running embedded linux 3.2.6 on an ARM processor. I am using a modified version of atmel's serial driver to control the 4 USART ports on my device. When I use the driver compiled with the kernel, all works fine. But I want to run the driver as a kernel module instead. I make all of the necessary changes and disable the internal driver and everything seems fine. The 4 tty devices are registered successfully and I can see that the all of my probe and initialization functions work correctly.

So here's the problem:
When I try to write to any of the devices, my "start transmit" function gets called but then waits for an interrupt from the usart which never occurs. So the write just hangs, and using a logic analyzer I can see that RTS gets asserted but no bytes show up on the tx line. I know that my call to request_irq succeeds and yet i never see any of the irq entries in /proc/interrupts. In the driver, I have also tried using request_irq to register a separate interrupt handler for a gpio line, and this works fine.

I know that this is a problem that is probably hard to diagnose, but I am looking for ANY possible suggestions that could lead me in the right direction to finding a solution. Let me know if you need any clarifications. Thank you

Comment: Another thought, when using the driver built in /proc/interupts shows the irq's registered as "AIC" irqs. Could there be something causing a disconnect between the Advanced Interrupt Controller and the loadable module?

Comment: What does *"I make all of the necessary changes and disable the internal driver"* mean?  Why do you have to "disable" the "internal" driver?  Does that mean that there could be two versions of the driver in memory?  Does this have something to do with the fact that the Atmel serial driver cannot be configured to be a loadable module through `make menuconfig`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did finally fix my problem. Thank you for the responses, none of them directly solved my problem but they did prompt further examination of my code. After some trial and error I finally got it working. I had originally moved the platform_device structures for each usart from /mach-at91/xxx_devices.c to my loadable module. Well for some reason the structures weren't getting the correct data to map to the hardware, I suppose because it wasn't correctly linking the symbols from the kernel (never got an error message though) and so some of the registration functions weren't even getting called. I ended up moving the structures and platform_device_register calls back into the devices file. I also decided to keep the driver for the console built-in using the original atmel_serial.c driver. I had to change the platform_device name for the console in both the devices file and in the built-in atmel_serial.c file in order for it to not conflict with my usart ports driver. I found that changing the platform_device and platform_driver name for the usarts from anything but "atmel_usart" resulted in usart transmission failing. I really don't understand why, but i'm just leaving it as atmel_usart so it works.

Thanks again to everybody who responded to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The symptoms reads like a *peripheral clock* that has not been enabled (or turned off): the device can be initialized w/o errors and an I/O operation can be setup, but the device doesn't do anything; it plays dead.  Since no I/O ever *starts*, you're never going to get an interrupt indicating *completion*!

The other thing to check are the conditional compilation directives for HW configuration structures in your `arch/arm/mach-xxx/zzz_devices.c` file.
Make sure that the serial port structures have something like:

```
#if defined(CONFIG_SERIAL_ATMEL) || defined(CONFIG_SERIAL_ATMEL_MODULE)
```

and not just

```
#if defined(CONFIG_SERIAL_ATMEL)
```

## Addendum

> I could be wrong but the clock shouldn't have any effect on the CTS pin causing an interrupt, right?

Not right.
These digital circuits are synchronous state machines: without a clock, a change-of-state by an input cannot be processed.
Also, SoCs and modern uControllers use the peripheral clocks as on/off switches for those integrated peripherals. There is often way more functionality, i.e. peripherals, on the silicon chip than can actually be used, mostly due to insufficient quantity of pins to the board. So disabling the clocks to unused devices is employed to reduce power consumption.

You are far too focused on interrupts.
You do not have a solvable interrupt problem; those are secondary failures.
The lack of output when attempting to transmit is far more significant and revealing.
The root cause is probably a flawed configuration of the USART devices, since transmitting bits is an automatic operation for a configured & operational USART.
If the difference between not-working versus working is *loadable module* versus *static linking*, then the root cause is going to be something fundamental (and trivial) like my two suggestions.

Also your lack of acknowledgement regarding the  `#if defined()`, e.g. you didn't respond with *"Oh yeah, we already knew that"*, raises a gigantic red flag that says **"Fix me first!"**

## Addendum 2

I'm tempted to delete this answer after discovering that the Atmel serial driver cannot be configured/built as a loadable module using `make menuconfig` (which is the premise for half of the answer). (Of course the `Kconfig` file *could* be hacked to make the config variable *tristate* instead of *boolean* to overcome the module restriction.)  I've left a comment for the OP.  But I also wanted to preserve the comment to Mr. Stratton pointing out how symbols in the `.config` file are (not) used.

Comment: Thanks very much for the helpful reply. I won't be able to test until monday. One thing i forgot to mention is that I tried toggling the CTS pin which should fire the interrupt as well but it failed too. I could be wrong but the clock shouldn't have any effect on the CTS pin causing an interrupt, right?

Comment: @user1415608 if the UART peripheral is not getting clocked, that probably would prevent all uart-related functions including interrupts (RTS, CTS, etc are likely GPIOs rather than part of the UART).  An unset UART interrupt enable bit might be another culprit.  Also consider why the transmit routine would be waiting on an interrupt - probably on the idea that the transmit register is not yet empty.  But that could be a mistaken assumption at startup, and one that will never clear.  You might try polling and printk'ing UART flag bits during driver startup, or even force sending a character.

Comment: @sawdust - I won't claim that CONFIG_SOMETHING_MODULE is an idea that has never been used, but the usual case is not to make a separate config option for a module, but rather to set the config option to 'm' rather than 'y' when configuring for a module.  Either will pass the #if defined test.  However it is true that not everything that will work as a built-in will work as a module; particularly for serial there could be some key code elsewhere in the kernel since serial is often the first debug channel.  Recursive grep on the entire tree for identifiers may be warranted.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - *" Either will pass the #if defined test."* -- That's not true for Atmel drivers; you do need to test for both symbols at compile time.  I've helped another developer with a similar issue (driver works when statically linked, no-go when loadable module) for another device on an Atmel AT91SAM SoC. And the suggested edit is of the exact same form as for other Atmel peripherals (**but not used for USARTs**) in AT91 `xxx_devices.c` files.

Comment: @sawdust - you seem to be missing the point.  Most linux drivers use the SAME symbol for both built-in and module forms, but define it to a different value, "y" or "m".  Either value will pass an #if defined test for that symbol.  A web search on "CONFIG_SERIAL_ATMEL" finds many hits, one for "CONFIG_SERIAL_ATMEL_MODULE" seems to find none - though I can't promise that there isn't code that uses such an unusual mechanism hiding *somewhere*.  (Maybe you can find it?)  Building a driver for an on-chip UART as a module is already a bit unusual.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - Your point apparently is in reference to the symbols generated from the`Kconfig` files and stored in `.config`.  Apparently you are not aware that symbols in `.config` are not exported directly into the C code, but rather are **tranformed**, e.g. in recent kernels to `include/generated/autoconf.h`.  I don't know about other vendors' code, but something like `CONFIG_SERIAL_ATMEL=m` in `.config` would be transformed into `#define CONFIG_SERIAL_ATMEL_MODULE 1` for the C preprocessor.  If you haven't worked with Atmel ARM, then you are uninformed about what I'm referring to.